# Подгрузка данных на страницу с Node.js сервера

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть страница с постами/ссылками/превьюхами, которая отправляется Node.js сервером, который берет информацию о местонхождении файлов из mongodb. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "загрузить еще контента" или при скроле до низа страницы, подгружались еще посты.

Как это реализовать? Я смотрел информацию о jquery ajax, но не увидев там адрес нахождения сервера, так и не понял, как он загружает данные.

Comment: `ajax` принимает `url` откуда загрузить данные. затем он делает запрос по этому `url` и возвращает результат. а что с этим результатом делать - вы дописываете дальше с помощью *js*. для этого Вам **придется** выучить что такоe `XHR` запросы и их способы реализации (одним из которых и есть `ajax`). если есть еще вопросы - задавайте

Comment: Ну надо просто функцию написать, которая будет подгружать новый контент. И повесить её как коллбэк для слушателя событий. То есть она будет отрабатывать либо по клику на кнопку, либо под достижении определенного значения скролла. Но там тоже не всё так просто в последнем варианте.

Comment: @Август спасибо! Я сделал, чтобы сервер отдавал json при запросе к серверу http://localhost:3000/ajax/model_id/album  Буду копать в эту сторону

Comment: @AlexSazonov спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех, у кого будет подобный вопрос, расскажу, что я понял.

Сервер отдает JSON таким образом:

```
app.get("/ajax/:model_id/:album_id?", function(req,res) {

    var json_var = {variable: 'value'};

    // сервер отдает json по заданному выше пути
    res.send(json_var);

});
```

Клиент обращается к серверу, чтобы получить JSON таким образом:

```
// При нажатии на кнопку
$('.btn_load').click(function() {

    //запрашиваю у сервера и получаю JSON в переменной data
    $.get("http://localhost:3000/ajax/model_id/album_id", function(data, status){
      console.log("--- Data ---");
      console.log(data);
      console.log("--- Status ---");
      console.log(status);
    });

 });
```

Всего-то